# Visual Studio debug - call stack is getting smaller with debug symbols

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, stack-trace, debug-symbols

I'm currently debugging a dump file (x86, optimized release) with Visual Studio 2015. With no symbols loaded at all, the call stack is really big and doesn't show any method names (obviously). When I load in the first debug symbols, the call stack is getting smaller. If I'm loading in all symbols, some of the calls completely disappear as it would have never been called. Is there a reason for this behavior?

No symbols loaded:
[image: no symbols]

Debug symbols of CameraGrabber.dll loaded:
[image: symbols CameraGrabber.dll]

Additionally loaded the roidll_vicam.dll debug symbols:
[image: symbols roidll_vicam.dll]

As you can see, the call into the CameraGrabber.dll is completely missing if I'm loading in all symbols.

Comment: Are you debugging with optimizations!? You should deactivate optimizations for that (by, for instance, running on the Debug default profile, if you did not change default optimization parameters)

Comment: @manatttta I only have the heap dump, so I can't really change that now.

Comment: @manatttta Debugging non-optimised code is useful when testing code you're developing. But once code is released and strange bugs occur, sometimes the only option is to debug optimised code. Post-mortem debugging, as in the OP's case, are a similar case. You don't always have the luxury of debugging non-optimised code.

Comment: @Angew sure, my bad. misread the question

Comment: Optimized C++ code requires PDB files to produce accurate stack traces.  Without them, the debugger is forced to guess and that doesn't always end up well, especially so if the frame-pointer omission optimization is used.  Scrap everything with __Ctanh(), an internal compiler helper function that uses a non-standard calling convention.   Speed and debuggability are opposing goals, when it is C++ then speed always wins.